# Java with SQL: how to work with ResultSet

Tags: java, sql

I have for example the following code line

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemID='"+ X +"'");
```

if item `table scheme` is: `ItemID,itemName,Count,location`

how does the row from the table "sit" in the ResultSet?
is there a way to take the entire row and push it to the first cell of ArrayList (that is the value i must return and i can not change it, for other queries with multiple line results each line will be in a different cell of the array)?

Comment: see the tutorial code here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over your resultset using [`ResultSet.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) and get the row information on every iteration and add it into your array list.

```
List<YourObj> ref = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemID='"+ X +"'");
while(rs.next())
      ref.add(new YourObj(rs.getName(), rs.getWhatever()));
}
```

Here's the reference from [Oracle Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)